# How do I alter the node entity?

Tags: nodes, 8, entities

Maintainer of Custom Publishing Options here... trying to figure out how to port to 8 in a clean way.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2647410

I have config entities working, so I can define custom publish options in the admin.

From here, I would like to add these options on the Node form(s), but they also need to be stored in node_field_data table. Previously hook_schema_alter / entity_info_alter was used to do this, example below:

D7:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_schema_alter().
 */
function custom_pub_schema_alter(&$schema) {
  $types = variable_get('custom_pub_types', array());
  foreach ($types as $type) {
    $schema['node']['fields'][$type['type']] = array(
      'description' => t('Custom publishing option @name', array('@name' => $type['name'])),
      'type' => 'int',
      'not null' => TRUE,
      'default' => 0,
    );
  }
}
```

D8:

```
function custom_pub_entity_base_field_info(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type->id() === 'node') {
    $fields = [];

    foreach (Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('custom_publishing_option')->loadMultiple() as $machine_name => $publish_option) {
      $fields['cpo_' . $publish_option->id()] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('boolean')
        ->setLabel(t('!label', ['!label' => $publish_option->label()]))
        ->setDescription(t('A status added by custom publishing options.'))
        ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
        ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
        ->setDefaultValue(FALSE)
        ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
    }

    return $fields;
  }
}
```

`$fields` looks good here, and no errors are thrown - yet, I do not see any change to the data in the database. I would expect fields to be added to the node_field_data table, what is missing here? hook_schema_alter() has been removed, is there a way to trigger this to update that I don't see?

The purpose of this module is to let admins define their own statuses to use with the default node statuses, which from there they can combine them for different Views/Rules/Action capabilities. Being set on the node similar to status/promote/sticky made it fairly quick.

Comment: I am sorry but you need to ask something more clear (on hop on IRC so we can have an iterative conversation) -- I do not know what you'd like to do.

Comment: Updating OG question.

Comment: You need to create the fields in a install hook / update hook, like \node_update_8001() does for example

Comment: These are declared by the user though - in the admin interface.

Comment: What about doing that same code in postSave/postDelete of the ConfigEntityBase form for this config entity?

Comment: NM - figured it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When entities are created, I had to do this to create them in the node table:

```
$manager = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();

if ($is_new) {
      // create the field definition for the node
      $storage_definition = BaseFieldDefinition::create('boolean')
        ->setLabel(t('!label', ['!label' => $label]))
        ->setDescription(t('!description', ['!description' => $description]))
        ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
        ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
        ->setDefaultValue(0)
        ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);

      $manager->installFieldStorageDefinition($id, 'node', 'custom_pub', $storage_definition);
    } else {
      $storage_definition = $manager->getFieldStorageDefinition($id, 'node');

      if (isset($storage_definition)) {
        // update the label and description on the definition
        $storage_definition
          ->setLabel(t('!label', ['!label' => $label]))
          ->setDescription(t('!description', ['!description' => $description]));

        $manager->updateFieldStorageDefinition($storage_definition);
      }
    }
```